# Bash get output from class

Tags: linux, bash

I've got a script, and I want to do something like this :

```
text1() {
something here
}

show(){
echo test1() 
and some text here
}
```

Basically I want to use output from the first <strike>class</strike> function in the second <strike>class</strike> function, how I can do this?

Comment: Those are functions not classes. And have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried to add one function to variable for example text=text1() also I tried something like in the code above, include one function inside the main one

Comment: @a8537994 There are many parts of the shell that are not like other languages. I suggest reading a bash tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put to a variable a value that function returns to `stdout`, use `$()`:

```
foo() {
    printf '%s\n' 'ququ'
}

bar() {
    VAR="$(foo)"
    echo "$VAR"
}
```

I. e. functions in GNU Bash (and other shells as well) are like external utilities.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is really what you want, but ...

You must know that bash functions, internal commands and standard tools *don't* return their output. Instead they write it on *stdout*. When you don't use any redirection, *stdout* is the terminal screen where you launched the command.

```
function text1() {
  echo "In text1()"
}

function show(){
  test1
  echo "In show()"
}
```

If I call `text1` from my terminal:

```
sh$ text1
In text1()
```

The *function* `text1` during its execution invokes `echo` that send output to *stdout*. I *see* the result on the console.

```
sh$ show
In text1()
In show()
```

Calling `show` executes `text1` (producing the same *output* as previously) followed by the output of the second `echo`.

---

If you want to *store* in a variable the intermediate result of a function or command, you might use the `VAR=$( ...)` notation. Think of that like "capturing" the output:

```
function text1() {
  echo "In text1()"
}

function show(){
  MYVAR=$(text1)
  echo "In show() where MYVAR = ${MYVAR}"
}
```

Please compare the output now, with the previous case:

```
sh$ show
In show() where MYVAR = In text1()
```